# Angular canvas is undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js

I am using `chart.js` in ionic angular app and I get this error:

```
this.barCanvas is undefined
```

## Code

`HTML`

```
<ion-card-content>
  <canvas #barCanvas></canvas>
</ion-card-content>
```

`Component`

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';

export class DashboardPage implements OnInit {
 @ViewChild('barCanvas', {static: true}) barCanvas: ElementRef;

 private barChart: Chart;

 constructor(...){...}

 ionViewDidEnter() {
   this.barChartFunction();
 }

 barChartFunction() {
  this.barChart = new Chart(this.barCanvas.nativeElement, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: '# of Submit',
          data: [1,2,3,4,5,6],
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
          ],
          borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
          ],
          borderWidth: 1
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [
          {
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  });
 }
}
```

**any idea?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solved

I've compiled `micronyks` answer with other codes and it's working now.

Here is how I've done it:

```
// Pay attention to added `read: ElementRef` (the most important part is this code
@ViewChild('barCanvas', {static: false, read: ElementRef}) barCanvas: ElementRef;
```

Then I added `AfterViewInit` to my component and placed my loading code into that

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.barChartFunction();
  }, 6000);
}

barChartFunction() {
  // my charts code...
}
```

Hope it comes handy for those in need.

Comment: The key thing here is put the chart function in the ngAfterViewInit, no need to have the setTimeOut at all, it works.

Answer (score 0):

**I don't understand IONIC** but,

I'm sure that `ionViewDidEnter` function runs before `ngAfterviewInit` life cycle hook of Angular component.

`ViewChild` instance get initialized or accessible ***ONLY*** in/after `ngAfterViewInit` life cycle hook.

So, You have to make sure that `ionViewDidEnter` runs once `viewChild` instance is accessible or make sure to run  `barChartFunction` function from `ngAfterViewInit` function.

Comment: thanks as much as i can understand `ionViewDidEnter` is same as `ngAfterviewInit` or I might be wrong `sources` 1- https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle 2- https://medium.com/@paulstelzer/ionic-4-and-the-lifecycle-hooks-4fe9eabb2864