# Unable to use HTML Canvas in the latest version of Angular and TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, html5-canvas

I searched through the internet for examples of using HTML canvas in Angular, and all the solutions I found don't work due to changes in syntax in Typescript and Angular in the new versions.

I'd be happy to find any help or example.
I already tried all kinds of things, but it seems like [StrictPropertyInitialization](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html) made all the current examples the tutorials obsolete.
Any attempts to make canvas work failed and raised TypeScript errors, including using different examples which appeared to work a few years back, like [@realappie's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4047409/realappie) [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/canvas-example?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts). Small changes in syntax people suggested do not work as well, like

```
@ViewChild('myCanvas', {static: false}) myCanvas: ElementRef;
```

or

```
@ViewChild('myCanvas')
private myCanvas: ElementRef = {} as ElementRef;
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you :)

Comment: In the title you write angular.js but the code and your tag suggest you are using angular. These two are not compatible. If you are using angular, update the title.

Comment: `@ViewChild('myCanvas', {static: false}) myCanvas!: ElementRef;`. the `!`say Angular, "yes I Know that can be null". BTW, use "static:true" if your canvas are always "visible" in your component -if it is not unde a div with e.g. a *ngIf-. use "static:false" (or remove it, it's the option by defect) if not, but remember that the element it is not disposible in ngOnInit -you can use ngAfterViewInit-

Comment: @Eliseo I tried that, but if I use ! it makes it possible for the object to be null, and that makes it impossible to use different kinds of methods and raises other errors

Comment: I feel that you has problem to translate javascript to typescript. See a few examples in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fjdwyi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) not to get the canvas. Think that in javascript when you use `var ctx` the variable is declared global and you can use anywhere. In typeScript the "variables" or belong to the component -when is decalred outside any function- or only work inside a function when you decalre with const. If you write the example you has problem it's more easy we can help you

Comment: @Eliseo I figured it out, wanted to say thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bit duplicate with this one and I think this one is greate:

[Angular canvas is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64256375/angular-canvas-is-undefined)